# PHP Session Variable Randomly Unsets

Tags: php, session

I have a PHP Session that I am using to manage my administration panel of my website. This uses two variables to monitor the session, `lastAction` and `user`. Recently, on one particular page of my website, the session variable `user` will randomly unset entirely and send the user back to the login page, but I cannot seem to figure out why.

```
session_start();

$fn = "timeout.txt";
$fh = fopen($fn,'r');
$to = fread($fh,filesize($fn));

if(abs(time()-$_SESSION["lastAction"]) > $to)
{
    session_unset();
    die("Timeout");
}

var_dump($_SESSION);

//Set timeout back to 0
$_SESSION["lastAction"] = time();

if($_SESSION["user"] != "...")
{
    die("Invalid User");
    header("Location:/login");
}
```

I never get the Timeout error, only the Invalid User error.

Sometimes when I dump the session variable, I get the array of two values, `lastAction` and `user`, but then, simply by reloading the page only a few seconds later, `user` gets unset, but `lastAction` does not.

Also, in this instance, I am reloading the page through javascript: `parent.location='';`

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: Is it possible that the sesssion has exceeded the php session timeout setting?

Comment: I don't think so; this happens randomly, and if I go directly to this page after logging in (perhaps only a minute later), 1 in 5 refreshes will unset the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This most likely has to do with your Header. The session variables are only good within the domain they are set in. For example, if you set the session vars in `www.example.com`, but then your header redirects to `example.com`, you will not have your session vars to use, same as if you redirected to `mobile.example.com`. Change that relative path I see in your code and see if that is what is causing it.

Comment: What relative path do you mean in particular, because I'm still getting logged out sometimes.

Comment: I don't know, I can't see all the pages or all the code that could be causing it. That is for you to look through. It could be a javascript redirect too, not just a header redirect. The main thing is to be consistent with your domains.

Comment: Is it possible that a 404 error on an image could be causing this?

Comment: Yep that was it! A 404 error was causing it. Thanks for your help!